# Combining multiple attributes in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, coding-style, attributes

Is there a functional difference between the following syntax...

```
[Foo, Bar]
public class Baz {}
```

...and this syntax?

```
[Foo]
[Bar]
public class Baz {}
```

Assuming each produces identical results when compiled, which is the preferred form?

Comment: I've only ever seen attributes written separate, like [Foo][Bar], and is what I do myself. I suppose it's really up to you, though.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**There is no functional difference. It's a question of convenience and style.**

Most often, I tend to see attributes on their own lines as a way to keep them separate and easy to read. It's also nice to be able to use the line comment `//` to remove attributes individually.

```
[A]
[B]
//[C] disabled
public class Foo {}
```

Comment: Also, because attributes tend to have longer names than `A` and `B` so lines can get pretty long if you put them all together!

Answer (score 11):

From a readability standpoint separate attributes are preferred.

Think about the case where you are passing some type of parameter

```
 [Foo(typeof(int)), Bar(typeof(decimal), MessageTemplate="Bar")]
```

versus

```
 [Foo(typeof(int))]
 [Bar(typeof(decimal), MessageTemplate="Bar")]
```

I would also argue, if you could combine them into one, they should be one tag.

Answer (score 3):

I typically stack attributes.  But I also mainly use these with WCF where the parameter list can get pretty big.

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebGet(...)]
string MyMethod(string input);
```