# Cannot define `Name` attribute on WebAPI2 method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

In Mike Wasson's [WebAPI2 tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-names), the `Name` attribute of a route is clearly defined like this:

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/books/{id}", Name="GetBookById")]
    public BookDto GetBook(int id) 
    {
        // Implementation not shown...
    }
}
```

However, when I try this in my own code (albeit VB) I can an error:

> Type 'Name' is not defined

Is anything wrong with my approach?

[image: VS error details]

Comment: Try just removing it, afaik its just a name for the route and it doesn't need one to work.

Comment: If only... :-/  I need the Name to dynamically create a URI back to the method elsewhere

Comment: Lol use C# like the rest of us!! Sorry, thats no help, dont know vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense to the rescue!!
Don't use the Name property name:

```
<Route("test/{cid}", "nameofroute", 0)>
Public Function [Get](cid As Int32)

End Function
```

Comment: Good work.  Thanks.  And yes, I take your point on C#.  I wish I'd chosen it ten years ago when I started with ASP.NET but my classic ASP skills were VB so it was an easy transition.  It's on my to-do list though...

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you use will allow for [multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546924/combining-multiple-attributes-in-c-sharp). This causes the compiler think you want to use a `NameAttribute`, which doesn't exist.

Remove the closing parenthesis after the route string and use the "pascal assignment operator" `:=`:

```
<Route("api/books/{id}", Name:="GetBookById")>
```

As shown on [Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-5).

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I chose to accept Matt's answer though as he posted a few seconds earlier.