# Combine several attributes in one attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

Is it possible to combine several attributes with only one?

Say that I have this property with `[Display]` and `[JsonProperty]`

```
[Display(Name = "String", Description = "A string", Order = 0)]
[JsonProperty]
public string StringProperty { get; set; }
```

Could I create a new attribute `[DisplayAndJsonProperty]` which implements both attributes somehow so that I can use that instead like below?

```
[DisplayAndJsonProperty(Name = "String", Description = "A string", Order = 0)]
public string StringProperty { get; set; }
```

In my case I'm using a base class decorated with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` to control serialization and then I need to decorate all properties I want to serialize with `[JsonProperty]`

Comment: Sure you can, it all depends on the client that **uses** this attributes. Having said this, without you indicating what attributes you´re using and in which context you´re using them, it´s **impossible** for us to help you any further. But anyway, what if there´s a thrid atttribute, which may be combinable to attribute1 but not to attribute2? Your appraoch will soon get a nightmare.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Just wanted to write no, you can't. - since you cannot derive from two classes, its the only idea that comes to mind. Now I am curious how your solution looks.

Comment: @RandRandom By just extending the logic that scans for one attribute to also look for two others? E.g. `methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Attribute1) > 0 || methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Attribute1And2) > 0)`. No inheritance needed.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Maybe I misunderstood the question, but what scannig are you talking about? - I understood it like this - he has `class FooAttribute { string Foo { get; } }` and `class BarAttribute { string Bar { get; } }` and instead of defining both attributes to his member - he wants to only define one (for whatever reason) but with both implementation of the single attributes so the only way I would see is `class CombinedAttribute : FooAttribute, BarAttribute` - maybe I misunderstood?!?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I updated the question with a real case

Comment: Again: **every** attribute has to parsed by some framework. Only because an attribute exists doesn´t add *any* functionality to your class. So it completely depends on the framework if or if not you can add further attributes. In your case you seem to have some JSON-serializer, possibly NewtonSoft or similar. There´s no way to say to that framework: hey, here´s a new attribute that you don´t know. Just handle it the following way. In short: unless you can´t modify that framework there´s no way to achieve this.

Comment: Having said this **why** do you want this? Which goal do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It sounds like the answer to my question is **no**. I understand that if I control the usage of the attributes I can of course get by with only one attribute. What I wondered was if you can decorate a property from within a custom attribute with other attributes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The reason I want to do this is to keep my solution tidy. I see that this can grow in some places and i would like to avoid having 5+ attributes on properties.

Comment: @OriginalUtter - not sure if it helps you at all but FYI you can write multiple attributes in a one-liner - see for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546924/combining-multiple-attributes-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Generally the answer is: you cannot do that.

An attribute is simply a "marker" for a framework. It instructs the framework how to treat a class, method, property, parameter, etc. in a special way. But it does **not** change the behavior of the decorated code.

The attributes are **a part of a framework**. Let me give you an example with ASP.Net.

```
class SomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPost("/api/do-something")]
    public void SomeAction([FromBody] SomeData someData){
       ...
    }
}
```

Both `[HttpPost]` and `[FromBody]` attributes belong to a ASP.Net framework. What we did above is essentially say:

"Hey ASP.Net, whenever somebody sends a POST request to "/api/do-something" URL, instantiate `SomeController` class object and call `SomeAction` method on it (thanks to `[HttpPost("/api/do-something")]`). When calling the method, grab whatever is in the request body, parse it to the `SomeData` object and pass the object to the `SomeAction`. (thanks to `[FromBody]`)"

ASP.Net using reflection finds all actions and maps them with routes. How? In this case it's looking for methods with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

If you used your own, custom attribute, it wouldn't be the part of the framework, so the framework wouldn't be aware of it and therefore wouldn't respect it.

You could probably use some post-compilation tools (like maybe [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)) which would replace your custom attribute with the desired attributes. Not sure though if there are any out-of-the-box solutions.

Personally I'd keep it simple and explicit and use original attributes. I'll be more readable especially for new members of the team. And obviously it wouldn't require post-compilation hacks :)